# How to translate point to chart scale in lightningchart js

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am trying to update my application to latest version of lightningchart js. Earlier I was using this method

```
  let point = translatePoint(location, series.scale,chart.engine.scale);
```

I researched I found translateCoordinate is the new method available. But I could not get around with this new method.
Can you please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation:

https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/docs/advanced-topics/coordinate-translations/